# Is there any way to use GWT 2.9 with Java 11 using Eclipse GWT plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, eclipse-plugin

We have a huge GWT project (GWT 2.7,  JDK 1.7, Eclipse) everything works perfect. We are planning to upgrade to Java 11 and GWT 2.9 which has been recently released. However Java 1.7 is retiring and getting obsolete we have to move on and upgrade. Since last week we are trying to create a development environment like the existing one but there is no success. I was wondering whether anyone out there is struggling with the same issue, any hint, solution or hacking the eclipse plugin would be greatly appreciated.

Eclipse plugin comes with GWT (2.7 and 2.8.1)

Comment: What issue exactly are you having?

Comment: GWT 2.8.2 supports running on Java 11, and GWT 2.9 supports using java 11 syntax, so either version should be fine for your purposes - can you explain what exactly isn't working - error messages, stack traces, logs, etc?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.

- download gwt-2.9.0.zip from gwtproject.org
- unzip it
- start Eclipse
- open the preference panel
- choose GWT -> GWT Settings
- add gwt 2.9.0 by pressing the add button on the right

[image: Eclipse Preference Window]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so far we have figured it out but with Java 11 Jetty does not start and has a few problems.

Comment: You can run GWT on other servers or use Spring Boot.